# GWT (Google Web Toolkit) CellBrowser Focus/Scrolling Problem

Tags: gwt, gwt2, cellbrowser

It appears that when the mouse is hovering over an item, in a cellbrowser column that should be able to scroll vertically, moving the mouse wheel has no effect.  Only when the mouse is hovering over the blank space between items in the cellbrowser column does the column's scroll bar correctly respond to the mouse wheel movement.  While this is merely a nuisance on a PC browser, it causes the control to be virtually unscrollable on the iPad Safari browser.  Only while you press two fingers within the whitespace between items can you scroll and, as soon as your fingers hit text, the scrolling stops.

A focus issue seems to be causing the scrolling problem and I was wondering if anybody had a workaround or fix for this problem that will enable the scrollable CellBrowser column to scroll properly on an iPad.

Comment: Is this question valid anymore?

Comment: @Anonymous:  I didn't get you!